snap permissions browser and thunderbird
I am on Ubuntu 24.10.
I believe I have done something to my installation to mess up Snap permissions. The result is that the default Firefox install, Chromium and Thunderbird cannot upload files from my laptop, or download files from the Internet.
I have installed the Mozilla provided deb version of Firefox for now but would like to fix my installation and successfully use the default Snap versions. I have no interest in uninstalling snap, snapcraft etc.
I could be wrong but I have an idea the problem stems from when I installed prompting-client and desktop-security-center.
Any help appreciated!

Ok, problem solved. I previously installed 'Desktop Security Center' and set it to require apps for system permissions.
I then uninstalled it.
Reinstalling it today allowed me to remove that requirement. Voila, everything started working as it should!
